# Извлечь каждое value c json в каждый span

Tags: javascript, json

У меня есть json с данными, я их получаю и вывожу в список, все ок. Но суть проблемы что в li заголовки статические и их нужно оставить а цифры нужно вывести рядом (я создал span). Так вот, как мне вывести каждое значение в каждом спане
мой код:

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var items = '';
$.each( data.constructions, function( key, val ) {
  items += '<span>' + val + '</span>';
});
$(".card-list-manager span").append(items);
```

```
<ul class="card-list-manager">
    <li>Количество проданных конструкций: <span>82288</span></li>
    <li>Выполнение плана: <span>80.7%</span></li>
    <li>План на месяц: <span>100465</span></li>
    <li>Прогноз на конец месяца: <span>100465</span></li>
    <li>Прирост относительно прошлого месяца: <span>30.7%</span></li>
</ul>
```

Мой json:

```
{
  "constructions" : {
    "qty": 82288
    "performance": 80.7
    "plan": 100465
    "forecast": 92288
    "growth": 30.7 
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то чего вы добиваетесь, то вот. В противном случае опишите подробнее.

```js
var data = {
  "constructions": {
    "qty": 82288,
    "performance": 80.7,
    "plan": 100465,
    "forecast": 92288,
    "growth": 30.7
  }
};
$items = $(".card-list-manager").eq(0); //Получили контейнер с li элементами
let i = 0; //Cчетчик дочерних элементов
$.each(data.constructions, function(key, val) {
  $temp = $items.children().eq(i); //Дочерний элемент
  $temp.append('<span> ' + val + '</span>'); //Добавляем значение в span( В принципе можно обойтись и без него )
  i++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="card-list-manager">
  <li>Количество проданных конструкций:</li>
  <li>Выполнение плана:</li>
  <li>План на месяц:</li>
  <li>Прогноз на конец месяца:</li>
  <li>Прирост относительно прошлого месяца:</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: это то что мне нужно, спасибо!

Comment: Минус такого подхода в том, что если поменять порядок елементов в массиве или в DOM - цифры будут не на своих местах.

Comment: @ДавидМанжула да, все верно